# Problem with .htaccess on server (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, canvas, webserver, vendor

I just deployed my Laravel project to the webserver. I added  the [austintoddj/canvas](https://github.com/austintoddj/canvas) package. Now I have the following structure on my server.

`public_html` -> contains the original public folders contents (`.htaccess` points to `index.php` and in `index.html` the path is changed to search in myBlog) - That part is working as expected
`myBlog` -> contains everything else, however when I installed the package mentioned above it created a public folder with a vendor in it that is used by the package and that is the part which is problematic. The CSS and JS files are not seen.

I have a `.htaccess` in the root of my myBlog project.

```bash
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>`
```

If I try to run the project locally with `php artisan serve` everything works perfectly, but when I try to run it with XAMPP I get the same result as in the web server (the UI elements not loading).

Have anyone encountered that before? Don't really understand with its not loading up the files.

I tried to put everything in `public_html` it works but security-wise it's not a good idea, also tried to debug with no luck.

Comment: What is your `DocumentRoot` set to?  Did you change it to point to something other than `public_html`?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just install `myBlog` inside `public_html`?

Comment: I read that is not a good idea to install in public_html, since that way all my code will be exposed

Comment: I did not change the document root, how do I check if it is still set to the public_html?

Comment: It would be in your web servers configuration files. If you're on shared hosting you probably don't have any control over the Document root